# How improve readability of JSON string formatting when or after using SerializeJSON

Tags: json, serialization, format, coldfusion-10

Using ColdFusion 10, I created a struct and returned a JSON string after using SerializeJSON.

```
    <cfreturn serializeJSON(stcResult)>
```

The string returned looks like this:

```
{"errors":[{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"}]}
```

I want the JSON to look something like the example below. How can I format it with different indentation levels, so it is more readable?

```
{
    "errors":[
        {"key1":"value1"},
        {"key1":"value1"}
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found a solution [http://ketanjetty.com/coldfusion/javascript/format-json/](http://ketanjetty.com/coldfusion/javascript/format-json/), just need to change '+' to '&' and change '&nbsp;' to ' ' or chr(32) when using CFSCRIPT.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does it matter? :) Typically you are just passing JSON to another process for parsing, so syntax matters, but "pretty" spacing and indenting are irrelevant.

Comment: @Leigh no, I need to display the json not passing to another process, so I need to easier to read.

Comment: Gotcha. You should post your solution as an answer, so it is more visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [solution](http://ketanjetty.com/coldfusion/javascript/format-json/), just need to change '+' to '&' and change `'&nbsp;'` to ' ' or chr(32) when using CFSCRIPT.